# Big images preview

Tags: image, modal-dialog, panning

I am working on an application for sharing a scanner. I have a webform for all the settings, a "Scan" button, and a "Preview" button. When the user press "Scan" nothing on the interface changes. A "Save As" window pops-up. But what should happen when the user press "Preview". I was thinking about a dialog window containing the scanned preview, but the images are usually too big (1248x1640 for example)?

Comment: What do you need the Preview for? Could you just throw this button away and provide some post-scan tools like crop, rotation, greyscale transform which are applied to scanned image?

Comment: As I have a webform for the settings, the user needs to see what settings work for the current image. There should be a preview button, as I'm not providing any post-scan image manipulation because it's too much work and I'm trying to keep this project simpler.

Comment: Then you can just scale big image, as it's just a rough view. Browsers do images scaling rather good.

Comment: But I want to stay in the application. Is it gonna be a good approach to load the image in an iframe, which is in a modal dialog window?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following idea. Click on zoom control or preview picture opens bigger image. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Дякую! :) When "click" happens on "Preview" button, a dialog window opens with a slider (html5 range element) and the image above it. You can zoom and pan the image in it's container similar to the example you gave me. However I can't upvote your answer, because I don't have enough reputation.